# Override enum cases in subclass

Tags: swift, enums

I have a Swift file which declares an enum, which I use in the functions in the class which is defined in the file:

```
class EnumTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    enum SectionType {
        case undefined
    }

    public func sectionType(for sectionNumber: Int) -> SectionType {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to descend from this class and override the enums in the descendant (each of my descendants needs different functionality, so the values of the enums have to be unique), and still be able to call the superclass's helper methods.

```
class ExampleTableViewController: EnumTableViewController {
    enum SectionType {
        case undefined
        case first
        case second
        case third
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let sectionType = self.sectionType(for: section)

        ...
    }
}
```

In Objective-C I could simply override the enum like I envisioned above, but there is no way to alter or override it in Swift, as far as I know. Obviously I need some other solution, but I don't know what to look for.

Two things are important for me: 1. to be able to use enum features (like tab completing and switch-cases) and 2. to have the same functions which take this enums as parameters only at one location without repeating them in every class.

Comment: Can you show some code demonstrating the thing that you want to do with overridden enums? It doesn't have to be working code.

Comment: Added code examples

Comment: I'm guessing that `ExampleTableViewController` will have its own version of `sectionType(for:)` right? Otherwise `EnumTableViewController` would need to know about its subclasses. Or do you intend that `sectionType(for:)` simply accesses an overridden dictionary `[Int, SectionType]` in the subclass to see what type of section it should be?

Comment: `ExampleTableViewController` would not implement `sectionType(for:)`. The reason `EnumTableViewController` exists for is to have a common place where these functions are implemented (there are plenty of them).

Comment: Okay, so how would `EnumTableViewController` implement `sectionType(for:)`? It needs to know what `SectionType` there are, right? For example, how is `EnumTableViewController` going to know which section type is section 0, if it doesn't know what type of sections there are?

Comment: It does rely on the concrete enum cases (they can be anything in any number), only has to be able to iterate through them and compare them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206800/discussion-between-sweeper-and-gklka).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Sweeper, it seems, that the solution is something similar:

```
protocol EnumTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    associatedtype SectionType
}

extension EnumTableViewController {
    func sectionType(for sectionNumber: Int) -> SectionType? {
        ...
    }
}

class ExampleTableViewController: UITableViewController, EnumTableViewController {
    typealias SectionType = ExampleSectionType

    enum ExampleSectionType {
       case first
       case second
       ...
    }
}
```

So basically I had to split the functionality of the `EnumTableViewController` into a protocol (which was a better fit anyway) and a `UITableViewController` extension. Since the protocol can't know anything about the descendant's enum implementation, I had to use `associatedtype` instead of any concrete type.